# How to use Click after getting text of an autogenerated time stamp

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Using Java/Selenium and Page Objects, I have to create an item name that is auto generated using the current date and time and entered into a text field. I then have to verify that this item was created on a different page. I am storing the name (current date/time) in a string via locating the element and getting the value but at certain points this name will be a link that needs to be clicked.

How do I make the saved String name clickable?

Ex: Currently storing as 
`String name = ad.name1.getAttribute("value")`

Cannot execute name.click()

Comment: Could you provide the Dom for both the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope what you want to do is :

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(name)).click()
```

You already have the link text stored in the variable 'name' . So once you are in the target page , use above command .

Answer (score 0):

After storing the name like `String name = ad.name1.getAttribute("value")` wait untill the value change to aclickable link.
Then locate the same element with a different criteria and click on it.

Comment: That won't work because the created value is on one page and i need to find whatever the value is on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a String. It cannot be clicked.
The only thing that can be clicked by Selenium is `WebElement`.

You need to find element by some locator that cointains 'name' and then click it.

Without DOM and your code is hard to guess how to fix it.
It might be something like:

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]"));`